# Dropbox Camera Upload for Camera FV-5 raw (DNG) photos

Tags: nexus-5, camera, photos, dropbox, cloud

On Nexus 5 & Android 5, [Camera FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro) can capture raw photos, stored in DNG format.

How can I upload the DNG files automatically to some kind of cloud storage?

For example, the "Camera Upload" feature in Dropbox seems to ignore DNG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Dropsync PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync.pro), that will do what you want.